# How to apply conditional duplicate removal for list of data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have list of data.frame that needed to apply very specific duplicate removal method. I have reason for using specific conditional duplicate removal for this data.frame list. However, duplicate removal condition for each individual data.frame is different. I want to do complete duplicate removal for first list element; for second list element, I need to search the row that appear more than twice (freq >2), and only keep one row; for third list element, search over the row that appear more than three times (freq>3), and keep two rows in that data.frame. I am trying to get more programmatic, dynamic solution for this data manipulation task. I tried my shot to get nice solution, but couldn't obtain my desired output. How can I make this happen easily ? Any way to accomplish this task more efficiently respect to my specific output ? Any idea please ?

reproducible data.frame:

```
myList <- list(
    bar= data.frame(start.pos=c(9,19,34,54,70,82,136,9,34,70,136,9,82,136),
                    end.pos=c(14,21,39,61,73,87,153,14,39,73,153,14,87,153),
                    pos.score=c(48,6,9,8,4,15,38,48,9,4,38,48,15,38)),
    cat = data.frame(start.pos=c(7,21,21,72,142,7,16,21,45,72,100,114,142,16,72,114),
                     end.pos=c(10,34,34,78,147,10,17,34,51,78,103,124,147,17,78,124),
                     pos.score=c(53,14,14,20,4,53,20,14,11,20,7,32,4,20,20,32)),
    foo= data.frame(start.pos=c(12,12,12,58,58,58,118,12,12,44,58,102,118,12,58,118),
                    end.pos=c(36,36,36,92,92,92,139,36,36,49,92,109,139,36,92,139),
                    pos.score=c(48,48,48,12,12,12,5,48,48,12,12,11,5,48,12,5))
)
```

Because `myList` is outcome of custom function, data.frame can't be detached. I am seeking more programmatic solution to make this specific duplicate removal for my data. How can I make specific duplicate removal if input is list of data.frame ?

my desired output as follow:

```
expectedList <- list(
    bar= data.frame(start.pos=c(9,19,34,54,70,82,136),
                    end.pos=c(14,21,39,61,73,87,153),
                    pos.score=c(48,6,9,8,4,15,38)),
    cat= data.frame(start.pos=c(7,21,72,142,7,16,45,100,114,142,16,114),
                    end.pos=c(10,34,78,147,10,17,51,103,124,147,17,124),
                    pos.score=c(53,14,20,4,53,20,11,7,32,4,20,32)),
    foo= data.frame(start.pos=c(12,12,44,58,58,118,102,118,118),
                    end.pos=c(36,36,49,92,92,139,109,139,139),
                    pos.score=c(48,48,12,12,12,5,11,5,5))
)
```

**Edit** :

in second data.frame `cat`, I am going to look up the rows that appear three times, and keep that rows only once; if row appear twice, I don't do duplicate removal on that.

for third data.frame `foo`, I am going to check the rows that appear more than three times, and keep two same rows instead. This is what I am trying to make very specific duplicate removal for each data.frame. How can I get my output ?

How can I get my desired data.frame list? How can I make this happen easily? Thanks a lot !

Comment: This is certainly do-able but there may be some limit to how programmatic it is, unless there's a definite pattern in the logic. I take it that the pattern is that for each list item you'll always want to increase the # of allowable duplicates by 1, right?

Comment: Your expected output for `foo` looks wrong. `(118, 139, 5)` shows up three times.

Comment: Not sure if the expected output is correct or not.  Perhaps `library(data.table);Map(function(x,y) setDT(x)[x[,  .I[(1:.N)<=y] , .(start.pos, end.pos, pos.score)]$V1], myList, 1:3)`

Comment: @Hack-R yes, I tried to do that pattern. I am sure about the `expectedList`. Is that possible to get my output list? Thank you

Comment: @akrun Yes, I just tested it and I think that should be an answer;   Dan --  akrun's solution outputs a list `out <- Map(function(x,y) setDT(x)[x[, .I[(1:.N)<=y] , .(start.pos, end.pos, pos.score)]$V1], myList, 1:3); class(out)` "list"

Comment: @akrun I am sure about the my output list. Plus, your solution is quite interesting, but how can I get my desired data.frame list ?

Comment: @Dan Then, I might not have got the logic of your condition right.  In your expectedList, I find 12 36 48 rows repeated 2 times, while 118 139 5 3 times.

Comment: @akrun because `12, 36, 48` row appear six times in original list, so I am gonna keep it twice; while `118 139 5` appear exactly three times, I don't do any changes on that . in `foo` I am gonna evaluate the rows that appear more than three times, and keep same two rows; I am sorry for my fuzzy logic. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Hack-R I edit my post. Could you continue your thought please ? Thanks

Comment: @akrun Could I get bit more interpretation about using `.N`, `.()$V1` in the answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do this `Map` to subset the rows of the `list` elements based on a logical index created with the corresponding number specified in the vector (`1:3`).  Convert the `data.frame` elements in `list`  to `data.table` (`setDT(x)`) , grouped by the columns ('start.pos', 'end.pos', 'pos.score'), we get the number of rows (`.N`), create a logical index with `if/else` and get the sequence of rows that satisfies the condition specified in the OP's post, use `.I` to get the row index, extract that index column (`$V1`) and use that to subset the dataset.

```
library(data.table)
res <- Map(function(x,y) setDT(x)[x[,  .I[if(.N > y) seq_len(pmax(y-1, 1)) 
        else seq_len(.N)]  , .(start.pos, end.pos, pos.score)]$V1], myList, 1:3)
sapply(res, nrow)
#bar cat foo 
#  7  12   9 

sapply(expectedList, nrow) 
#bar cat foo 
#7  12   9
```

Comment: Could I get bit more interpretation about this data.table solution? using `.N`, `.()$V1` for which purpose ? I am quite new with data.table package. Understanding your solution is much helpful to learn about your idea. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Apply the following function to each data-frame of your list specifying the maximum frequency per row

```
removeDuplicate = function(df, freq=1) {

    # back up the dataframe and add a row id
    tmp = df;
    tmp$cnt = 1:NROW(df);
    # get each row frequency
    cnt = aggregate(cnt~., tmp, length);

    # merge the original data-frame and the row-frequency data-frame
    tmp = merge(df, cnt, by=names(df));
    tmp = rbind(
                tmp[tmp$cnt<=freq, names(df)], # keep all the rows which frequency is not greater than the max allowed
                cnt[, names(df)] # add all the other rows just once
            );

    return(tmp);

}
```

To apply the function to each data-frame I would do:

```
expectedList = myList
maxFreq = c(1, 2, 3)
for(i in 1:length(expectedList)) {

    expectedList[[i]] = removeDuplicate(expectedList[[i]], maxFreq[i])

}
```

but I think a more elegant solution using [`lapply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) can be found...

Answer (score 1):

```
# Separate individual dataframes
bar = myList$bar 
cat = myList$cat
foo = myList$foo

# We will need ddply command of plyr package
library(plyr)

#Count how many times the rows have repeated and put the value in the fourth column (V1)
bar = ddply(bar,.(start.pos,end.pos,pos.score),nrow)
cat = ddply(cat,.(start.pos,end.pos,pos.score),nrow)
foo = ddply(foo,.(start.pos,end.pos,pos.score),nrow)

# For each data.frame, change the number of repetions to appropriate number of times
# if the rows have repeated for more than the desired number of times
# i.e 1 for bar, 2 for cat, and 3 for foo
for (i in 1:nrow(bar)){
if (bar$V1[i] > 1){
bar$V1[i] = 1
}}
for (i in 1:nrow(cat)){
if (cat$V1[i] > 2){
cat$V1[i] = 1
}}
for (i in 1:nrow(foo)){
if (foo$V1[i] > 2){
foo$V1[i] = 2
}}

# Repeat each row for the number of times indicated in the fourth column.
# This will be 1 for bar, up to 2 for cat, and up to 3 for foo
bar = bar[rep(row.names(bar), bar[,4]), 1:3]
cat = cat[rep(row.names(cat), cat[,4]), 1:3]
foo = foo[rep(row.names(foo), foo[,4]), 1:3]

# Set the rownames to NULL if desired
rownames(cat) = NULL
rownames(bar) = NULL
rownames(foo) = NULL

# Combine the indivudal data.frames into a new list
expectedList = list(bar = bar,cat = cat,foo = foo)
```